# Running into an error when trying to install pandas and numpy in Pycharm on Windows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pycharm

I am receiving the following error messages:

Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions:none)

Error: No matching distribution found for pandas

I am also receiving a warning that there was an error checking the latest version of pip.
I'm currently using pip 22.3.1.

I tried installing it manually and through Pycharm.

Comment: Did you try to install the packages through the command prompt instead of pycharm? For example pip install pandas==1.5.2

Comment: @ganninu93 Okay, that seemed to work. I was using pip install pandas...I did not included ==1.5.2. Thank you!